# The meaning of 'formal'

Tags: sentence-structure, terminology, formal-language

> In a ***very formal*** style, *think* is sometimes followed by an object and an adjective or noun complement.
>
> > *They thought her fascinating.
> >
> >     We thought him a fool.*
>
> (M. Swan, Practical English Usage, 588.4)

It says 'very formal,' but my old dictionary says the structure, without '*to be*,' happens in speech.

How should I understand these? Does this 'formal' mean... I don't know if this is a reasonable word... form-oriented? I mean it's like form for form sake? What is the word for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such constructions are not used much in modern English. You will, of course, find them in period dramas, especially when the characters are upper-class or well-educated. So, yes, I would agree with Swan: both very formal and somewhat old-fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

A meaning of *formal* is "not casual" or "strictly following protocol or rules of etiquette/politeness" and that's what is meant here.

*Formal* does not mean "form-oriented" for any of the meanings of *form* - with one exception: etiquette can be considered a standard or "form" for behavior.